# Managing version conflicts between Kafka-Spark-Scala-Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, version

I have been recently working on a project that involves the integration of **Kafka**, **Spark** and **Cassandra**. One of the key things I noticed when trying to get the whole thing setup is that there are a lot of version conflicts that needs to be very carefully matched in order to get these technologies to work together.

In addition, it was important to take note of the **Scala** version used with **Spark** when writing your own **Spark-Jobs**.

A slight change in the version of one of the above technologies breaks the complete flow and requires a proper redo of matching them together.

The task was not very straight forward (at least for me and I guess it's the same for all) and *I am wondering how do companies which have these technologies working in sync actually manage this?*

As I see it, it is an important problem with new releases and bug fixes being rolled out, to keep these tools working together without a break.

Can someone who has experience with regards to this enlighten me as to how companies actually manage/maintain these conflicts?

Or is it an overstatement to say it's an actual problem?

Thanks in advance